# "curves of a compressor at different speeds" or "curves at different speed of a compressor"

Tags: word-usage

I encountered this problem when writing a report. The situation is that a compressor has several curves showing its performance. These curves are of different speeds. I want to discuss these curves. Is it right to say

```
curves of a compressor at different speeds
```

or

```
curves at different speeds of a compressor
```

Comment: "The compressor's performance curves at different speeds" is how I'd say it, using the possessive.

Answer (score 1):

"curves at different speeds of a compressor", is correct. Normally I think we would say, "different speed curves of a compressor"

curves of a compressor at different speeds is saying the compressor at different speeds, showing curves.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you mean, although these two still sound both alright for me.